# "Module is not a function" error in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack

I have a simple java script project consisting of two files:

```
test_project
   |- version.js
   |- index.js
```

version.js defines a simple data container:

```
module.exports =
    {
        products: [
            {product: 'p1', version: '?'},
            {product: 'p2', version: '?'},
            {product: 'p3', version: '?'},
            {product: 'p4', version: '?'}
        ]
    };
```

and index.js defines a module and then just requires version.js:

```
module.exports = module('TestProject', []);
require('./version');
```

I build this project using webpack without errors, but the resulting bundle fails at the following statement

```
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {module.exports = module('TestProject', []);
__webpack_require__(5);
```

With the error

> Uncaught TypeError: module is not a function
>       at Object. (TestProject.js:103)
>       at Object.160 (TestProject:106)
>       at **webpack_require** (TestProject.js:20)
>       at 15.module.exports.module.deprecate (TestProject.js:66)
>       at TestProject.js:69

What could be the problem?

Comment: You mean `angular.module` instead of `module`?

Comment: Should I use angular.module ?

Comment: Of course. `module` is entirely different thing.

Comment: Looks better, thanks. Can you formulate that as an answer, with a little bit of context information for js newbies such as me? I can accept it as an answer, then.